# Update data in multiple controllers from service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, callback

I want to update data in multiple controllers from a service. One option would be to broadcast/emit the data on `$rootScope`.

I would have to have hundreds of listeners, some listening for the same event, some for others. And an event would be dispatched every couple of seconds.

I have created a working solution that using callbacks and the possibility to unregister them. The weird thing is that I don't see anybody else using a similar solution which makes me wonder if there are some reason not to do  it like this.

**Service**

```
var callbacks = {};
var idCounter = 0;
function register(cb) {
  var id = idCounter++;
  callbacks[id] = cb;

  return function() {
    delete callbacks[id];
  };
}

function send(data) {
  for (var i in callbacks) {
    callbacks[i](data);
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
var d = service.register(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

$scope.$destroy(function() {
  d();
});
```

So I guess my questions are:

- Are there any reasons why I shouldn't use this kind of callback mechanism. (Memory leaks?)
- Should I just go with events instead? Performance irrelevant at this scale?
- Improvements?

Answer (score 0):

You reproduce concept of event and dispatcher.... Use it ! if function scope of `var d = ...` (in controller) pointer is not deleted, yes memory leaks. Also in service `var callbacks` is ugly slide effect, for this reasons prefer event is clean encapsulate and generic service !